# how to convert message to cipher message?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string message;
    cout << "Ahlan ya user ya habibi." <<endl;

    cout <<"what do you like to do today?" <<endl;
    cout <<"please enter the message:" <<endl;
    getline(cin,message);

    for(int i=0;i<message.size();i++)
    {
        if(string(message[i]==32))
        {
            cout<<char(message[i]);
        }
        else if(string( message[i])>=110)
        {
            int x = int(message[i])-13;
            cout<<char(x);
        }
        else
        {
            int x = string (message[i])+13;
            cout<<char(x);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

> E:\my programe\quiz\main.cpp|20|error: no matching function for call to 'std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>::basic_string(char&)'|
>
> E:\my programe\quiz\main.cpp|20|error: invalid conversion from 'char' to 'const char*' [-fpermissive]|
>
> E:\my programe\quiz\main.cpp|27|error: no matching function for call to 'std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>::basic_string(char&)'|
>
> E:\my programe\quiz\main.cpp|27|error: invalid conversion from 'char' to 'const char*' [-fpermissive]|

Comment: This isn't a huge deal, but on top of the feedback from the answer, you should consider just using `'n'` and `' '` rather than integers representing those values, as it makes your code more readable

Answer (score 1):

[`std::string::operator[]`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_at) returns a `char&` reference.  You are trying to construct temporary [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) objects with single `char` values as input, but `std::string` does not have any constructors that take only a single `char` as input.  That is why you are getting errors.

Even if you could construct a `std::string` from a single `char`, you can't compare a `std::string` to an integer anyway.

You don't need all of those `string()` (and `char()`) casts at all (BTW, your first `string()` cast is malformed anyway).  `char` is a numeric type.  You can compare a `char` value  directly to an integer, and add/subtract and integer directly to/from a `char` value to produce a new `char` value.

Try this instead:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string message;
    cout << "Ahlan ya user ya habibi." << endl;

    cout << "what do you like to do today?" << endl;
    cout << "please enter the message:" << endl;
    getline(cin, message);

    for(int i = 0; i < message.size(); i++)
    {
        if (message[i] == 32)
        {
            cout << message[i];
        }
        else if (message[i] >= 110)
        {
            char x = message[i] - 13;
            cout << x;
        }
        else
        {
            char x = message[i] + 13;
            cout << x;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/gcZiPK)